# Color Mixing with textures and different objects?

Tags: materials

I was wondering if there is a way to make mesh appear a different color when you put another mesh over it. [image]

Kinda like the picture shown above on how the circles are mixing to create a new color or even make a glowing object appear dark when another object is hovering over. Thank you.

Comment: Hello :). My answer was just an example of the *most obvious* solution. If you're looking for *advanced* solutions using dynamic paint/procedural textures, just say so :).

Comment: If you have another solution go for it, I hoping to learn as much as I can with Blender.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since Cycles is a physically-based engine... you can use a physically-based solution :).

[image]